# Inequality and limit question

Tags: probability

If I have an inequality, e.g.:
         $$\mathbb{E}|X(t+δ)-X(t)|²≤(aδ+bδ²)K$$
  say $a,b$ and $K$ are just constants, $X$,an arbitrary stochastic processes, then if I want to evaluate the limit $lim_{δ→0}$:
     $$\lim_{δ→0}(aδ+bδ²)K=0$$
  Is it correct to say then:
$$\lim_{δ→0}\mathbb{E}|X(t+δ)-X(t)|²=0$$ i.e. convert the inequality to an equality like this. I was told it was incorrect to do this because the difference of two stochastic processes (say any arbitrary stochastic process) could be negative, but i don't see how this is possible since it is the magnitude squared. Then the only possible solution would be zero

(I've corected the Y, to X(t))and yes euclidean metric.

Comment: Are the processes in some way dependent on $\delta$? Because if they aren't I can't see why the l.h.s. shouldn't be a continuous function of $\delta$ (a constant) and therfore $0$.

Comment: Is $X$ and $Y$ complex? or real?

Comment: how can the expected value of a squared random variable $Z^2=(X-Y)^2$ be zero??

Comment: It could tend to zero without being zero?

Comment: In principe it can of course. But what is the relation betewen $\Delta$ and $Z$? I can not see it. If there is no relation defined between them, the only result is $E(Z^2)=0$ which is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Squeeze/Sandwich Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem):

Given functions $g(x) \leq f(x) \leq h(x)$, and that $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ = $\lim_{x\to a}h(x) = L$. Then, $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = L$.

In your case, you have $f(δ) =\mathbb{E}|X-Y|²$, $g(δ) = 0$ and $h(δ) = (aδ+bδ²)K$. Looks legit.

Comment: I am assuming $\mathbb{E}|X-Y|²$ refers to the expected value of the square of the euclidean distance of $X$ and $Y$. As far as I know, euclidean distance cannot be negative (property of a metric).

Comment: how can you have a stochastic process with zero power?

Comment: Maybe i should say the left hand side tends to zero rather than equals zero. just to clarify, this is the same stochastic process incremented by a time of delta so it should be xt-x(t+delta) not Y,

Comment: $0 \leq \mathbb{E}|X(t+δ) - X(t)|²$ no?